# Constructor function returning object - documentation clarification?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find in the docs / understand this behavior for the following code :

I saw this piece of code [*here*](http://codingspot.com/2010/02/answering-the-juriy-zaytsev-javascript-quiz/):

```
 function f(){ return f; }
 new f() instanceof f;          //false
```

This is because ( from what i've [read](http://kourge.net/node/130)) :

> When the `constructor` returns an *object*, the `new` operator will yield
>   the returned *object*

So since `f` is a `function`   -  the `new` operator will yield  the returned *object* which is `f` in this case

So :  `new f() === f`

Hence : `f instanceof f`//false.

**Question :**

I 'm searching for this behaviour description in the docs  , but couldn't find it.

I only found partial answer in [**mdn**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description) :

[image]

However - looking at the [docs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.2) (which is what I really after) :

All it say is :

[image]

It **doesn't** mention  the cases where the `constructor` return `object or not`( i'm sure i'm missing it)

**Question:**
Where does in the docs  that behavior is  explained ?

nb ,

*I know that constructor function should not (generally) return anything , this question is for knowledge.*

nb2 :

example for this behaviour :

```
var z = {a: 2}; 
function g() { return z; } 
var x = new g(); 
x === z;  //true
```

Here, x is actually equal to z, **down to the identity!**

Comment: Can you please highlight your actual question?

Comment: @thefourtheye  Im looking the reference in the docs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because this behavior is a property of the [internal `[[Construct]]` method](http://es5.github.io/#x13.2.2), not `new`:

> 1. Let `obj` be a newly created native ECMAScript object.
>   [...]
>   8. Let `result` be the result of calling the `[[Call]]` internal property of `F`, providing `obj` as the this value and providing the argument list passed into `[[Construct]]` as `args`.
>   9. If `Type(result)` is `Object` then **return** `result`.
>   10. **Return** `obj`.

`F` is the function that is called via `new` (`f` in your case). Since `f` returns an object (step 8), it is returned (step 9). If it was not an object, the object in step 1 would be returned (step 10).

`new` simply returns what `[[Construct]]` returns:

> 5. Return the result of calling the `[[Construct]]` internal method [...]

Comment: `[[Construct]]` returns  what? it's just `f` no ?

Comment: I quoted that part in my answer. Either it returns what the function `F` returned (*"Let result be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal property of F"*) or the object created in the first step (*"return obj"*). And yes, in your example it would be `f`, because that's what the function returns (step 8 and 9).

Comment: `[[Construct]]` is the name of the internal method. --- Sorry can't read, ignore this comment.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is found [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2). The documentation of the *NewExpression* you reference above specifies that it

> returns the result of calling the [[Construct]] internal method

The spec for the [[Construct]] method is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Page 100 [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf):

...
8 Let result be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal property of F, providing obj as the this value and providing the 
argument list passed into [[Construct]] as args.

**9 If Type(result) is Object then return result.**

10 Return obj.